Is this a contradiction in the Bible please explain
How did Judas die: by hanging himself as described in Matthew 27:5, or by falling and his body bursting open as described in Acts 1:18?

Some suggestions for next time. 1) The Title should be a short question that other people might search for when they want to know, and no one is going to search for "is this a contradiction" or "please explain". The suggested duplicate question has a simple and useful Title. 2) When you enter a question several existing questions will be listed. You should check them to see if any of them already answer your question. (And this works best if you have a good Title question.)

And, welcome to the site.  You should read the Christianity Stack Exchange Tour page, and visit the Help Center for additional information.

All of these so-called 'contradictions' may be researched on Google and all have been asked already and answered already. Many have been answered already on this site and on Stack Exchange - Biblical Hermeneutics.
